# SQL statement with pagination and sorting

Tags: sql-server, pagination

I have two tables **UserProfile** & **UserConnections** with **ManyToMany** relationship.
Table **UserConnections** has two feilds "**uniqueProfileID**" & "**connectionProfileID**", both the fields are foreign key of same field from the Table **UserProfile** which is "**uniqueProfileID**".
It is like in Table **UserConnections**, one **uniqueProfileID** can have many **connectionProfileID** .

I need to retrive **uniqueProfileID** and **ProfileName** from table **UserProfile** where **connectionProfileID** is not in **uniqueProfileID** of the Table **UserConnections**, i also need to implement pagination in the query.

I have written the query like this, but i am getting an error "**The multi-part identifier "UP.ProfileName" could not be bound.**"

```
SELECT * FROM  
      ( 
      SELECT RoRowConstrainedResult2.* ,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY UP.ProfileName ASC) RowNum
      FROM      
      (
      SELECT UP.uniqueProfileID,UP.ProfileName,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UP.ProfileName ASC) RowNum2
      FROM dbo.UserProfile UP LEFT JOIN
      dbo.UserConnections UC ON UC.connectionProfileID = UP.uniqueProfileID
      WHERE ProfileName LIKE ('abhi' + '%') AND UP.uniqueProfileID NOT IN 
      (select Distinct(connectionProfileID) from dbo.UserConnections WHERE uniqueProfileID = 42) AND UP.uniqueProfileID !=42) RoRowConstrainedResult2
      )  RowConstrainedResult       

  WHERE    RowNum >= 1 AND RowNum <= 2
```

I am getting the error in the 3rd line in ORDER BY **UP.ProfileName**

I tried to fix this for more then a day but I couldn't.

Comment: _I am getting the error in the 3rd line in ORDER BY UP.ProfileName_, So can you show us the error message?

Comment: leave out 'UP.'; it is only an alias within RoRowConstrainedResult2,

Comment: wow, thank you so much, i spent a day in fixing this. Thanks.

Comment: thank you for helping. It worked, One more thing i wanted to know that if it is possible to also get the total count of the result returned by this query??

Comment: Remove signature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alias `UP` is from inside the sub-query, the alias you gave for the results of the inner most sub-query is `RoRowConstrainedResult2`. Just change the third line as shown below.

```
   SELECT * FROM  
          ( 
          SELECT RoRowConstrainedResult2.* ,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY RoRowConstrainedResult2.ProfileName ASC) RowNum
          FROM      
          (
          SELECT UP.uniqueProfileID,UP.ProfileName,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UP.ProfileName ASC) RowNum2
          FROM dbo.UserProfile UP LEFT JOIN
          dbo.UserConnections UC ON UC.connectionProfileID = UP.uniqueProfileID
          WHERE ProfileName LIKE ('abhi' + '%') AND UP.uniqueProfileID NOT IN 
          (select Distinct(connectionProfileID) from dbo.UserConnections WHERE uniqueProfileID = 42) AND UP.uniqueProfileID !=42) RoRowConstrainedResult2
          )  RowConstrainedResult       

      WHERE    RowNum >= 1 AND RowNum <= 2
```